# PowerShell DataAdapter.Fillでエラー

Tags: mysql, powershell

```
$ConnStr = "Server=$Server;port=$Port;uid=$User;pwd=$Pass;database=$Database;Pooling=$Pooling;charset=$CharSet"
$Conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($ConnStr)

$Conn.Open
$Sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE cid = $cid;"
$Cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Sql, $Conn)
$DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Cmd)
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$DataCnt = $DataAdapter.Fill($DataSet, "table") | Out-Null
```

最後の
`$DataCnt = $DataAdapter.Fill($DataSet, "table") | Out-Null`
の行で以下のエラーになってしまいます。

```
ERROR : "2" 個の引数を指定して "Fill" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
型 [DataTable] が見つかりません。この型を含むアセンブリが読み込まれていることを確認してください。 
"2" 個の引数を指定して "Fill" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
"2" 個の引数を指定して "Fill" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
"1" 個の引数を指定して "Fill" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
型 [Dataset] が見つかりません。この型を含むアセンブリが読み込まれていることを確認してください。 
型 [DataTable] が見つかりません。この型を含むアセンブリが読み込まれていることを確認してください。 
"2" 個の引数を指定して "Fill" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
"2" 個の引数を指定して "Fill" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
"2" 個の引数を指定して "Fill" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
"0" 個の引数を指定して "Open" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
"0" 個の引数を指定して "Open" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." 
"0" 個の引数を指定して "Open" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataAdapter.Fill`よりももっと手前、`MySqlConnection.Open`でエラーが発生しているかと。

> "0" 個の引数を指定して "Open" を呼び出し中に例外が発生しました: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."[0]

ちなみに

> ```
> $Conn.Open
> ```

のようにメソッド名だけを記述した場合、メソッド呼び出しは行われず、`delegate`（≒関数ポインター）が取得されるだけなので、意図通りのコードではないものと思われます。